# Reset Postgres query cache

Tags: postgresql, cache

I'm comparing some queries, on my particular dataset, between MySQL and Postgres.  Is there a Postgres equivalent to MySQL's "RESET QUERY CACHE"?

Comment: From what I understand Postgres doesn't use a query cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a post on serverfault a while ago that covered this topic.

Check this out...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216660/see-and-clear-postgres-caches-buffers

I hope that helps.

David

Comment: I think you mean StackOverflow but the information is just as useful either way!